# Relationship attributes having relations with another entity

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship, erd

I am creating an ER Diagram for an assignment using UML and cannot find much information on using relationship attributes. Can relationship attributes have relations with another entity?

I have drawn a picture of what I mean. Is the relationship between insurance and the attributes legal?

[image]